# Implementing a SAD(Sum of absolute differences) algorithm

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm implementing a JAVA program to find similarities between different frames of images.
Currently I'm using two different algorithms to achieve that.
Basically I divide the image in n*n blocks of pixels and calculate [SAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences) for them and compare.
Now my main problem is getting a value that is significative of a certain pixel, currently I'm getting pixel value in two different ways:

rgb values are 0-255

```
 //average pixel value
 double pixelValue = (getRed() + getGreen() + getBlue()) / 3.0;
```

or either

```
 //sum of RGB as a data for pixel value
 double pixelValue = (getRed() + getGreen() + getBlue());
```

Problem is both ways those value are not really significative for a pixel since a pixel completely blue or completely red would give the same value so if my n*n blocks are really small it can match wrongly.This poses significant problems with gradient images or similar.
What are good methods or functions of getting a pixel value as an integer or floating point number that is a good indicator of a pixel?
Mathematical functions are good(or even better) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A color image uses three dimensions to encode information at every spatial location.
It is (normally) not possible to find a single unique value that uniquely "identifies" a certain pixel.

However, there are different mathematical techniques that can be used to get maximum variability in a single channel.

The most naive method is simply to generate a 24 bit number out of the concatenation of the R, G, and B channels. This leads to problems, however, that a difference function would respond very differently to changes in each of the three channels depending on the order that they are concatenated.

You have already explored the possibility of the sum of the three channels, and have pointed out that this has some significant drawbacks.

Now, for more mathematically rigorous options:

An RGB color can be thought of as a vector in a three dimensional space, where each dimension is one of the color channels. A mathematical tool called [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (PCA) can be used to find a new set of orthogonal basis vectors that the 3D space can be projected into. These new vectors have the property that each successive vector maximizes the variance along that vector. The value of the first vector can then be used as an optimal estimator for each pixel. However, the PCA vectors must be computed from a set of data, which means that the PCA vectors are different for each image. Also, PCA computation can be very expensive.

A cheap alternative exists that can also be used. For natural images, the first PCA normally corresponds very well to the human perception of luminance (no coincidence, our human visual system has evolved very efficiently). For an RGB image stored using the sRGB primaries (almost all consumer RGB images), a simple linear transform exists to calculate [Luma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_%28video%29), which is then a good approximation of luminance.

The function most often used is:

```
Y' = 0.2126 R' + 0.7152 G' + 0.0722 B'
```

This function will give a good approximation of the maximum variance in a single channel.

So, unless you really need the best possible solution (PCA), the Luma equation above will give a good approximation. However, because you are reducing the dimensionality of your data, you will (almost) never get perfect results.

Comment: While I've implemented the Luma calc and trying it right now, I'm really interested in PCA and will definitely read more and try to implement it.Not only to get pixel value but because paired with SAD could help me with pairing matching blocks possibly more effectively.

Comment: It perhaps could. Choosing a good dataset to calculate the principal components from is important; the principal components for one image may not be the same as the next, and comparing values between different PCA sets it not mathematically meaningful. Just make sure that all of your data that you are comparing is projected into the same PCA space.

Comment: Also, don't forget that you can accept my answer if you think I satisfactorily answered your question.

Comment: Yes sure, I was just testing. I've tried using an algorithm similar as described in this paper [Two-stage Image Denoising by Principal Component Analysis with Local Pixel Grouping](http://www4.comp.polyu.edu.hk/~cslzhang/paper/PR_10_x_3.pdf) where i'm searching not only for corresponding blocks between frames but pixels surrounding them as well [result](http://imgur.com/rlI7XDz,AzLejws) .Unfortunately it takes around 1 minute per frame, which is slow and the results are similar to my actual implementation which instead can be run in quasi real time with 4x4 blocks( example was with 4x4 blocks)

Comment: Yeah, the PCA algorithm is not fast; it boils down to finding the `n` eigenvectors with the maximum eigenvalues, which boils down to a very large pseudoinverse, an inverse, and several matrix multiplications.